# JS: How to store values in an array in a loop(each) and compare this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, match

I am working on a little plugin that checks a couple of inputs if they have the same value(s). I think the best way to do this is to store the values in an array and check if the values are unique, or is there a better way to do this?

// the idea

```
$('input').each(function(){
   var type = $(this).attr('class');//can be a other attribute
   switch(type){
      case: 'red':
      // some code
      break;

      case: 'green':
      // some code
      break;

      case: 'black':
      // the code to see if all inputs with the class black 
      //if they have the same value return in true or false, if all of the values
      // are empty it should return false
      break;

      // more cases....
   };
});
```

Comment: If you want to check the *values* of the inputs, why does your code look at the "class" attribute? Oh, wait; you want to check for similar values by class ... Well, that's going to be a pretty fragile thing to do, because an element can have more than one "class" value; or, more properly, the "class" is semantically a *list* of values.

Comment: What does "return in true false" mean?

Comment: What is the datatype that these inputs can return?

Comment: Also - why store the classes in the array don't you just want to know if they are all the same or not? Just assign first's element class to a variable and compare it to the others..,

Comment: The class is just an idea, i will be using html5 data attributes. The return in true of false is that if all are the same it should return true, if not, return false. Datatype? And no i dont want to store the classes, but the values of the inputs that have the same classes.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an object for it:

```
var values = {};
var dupFound = false;
$(...).each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(values[value]) {
        dupFound = true;
    }
    else {
        values[value] = this;
    }
});
```

This has the advantage that you can easily access the other element containing the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkMatchingValues(cssClass) {
    var value, matching = true;
    $('input#' + cssClass).each(function() {
        if(value == undefined) {value = this.val(); return}
        if(value != this.var()) {matching = false; return}
    }
    return matching;
}
```